# ng-model for md-datepicker must be in date format

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-material

Our team is creating a mdDialog that brings up a tabbed form and using ng-switch for different input types.  Our ng-model works on choice inputs, boolean inputs, and string inputs, but keep getting an error for mddatepicker.

```
<div ng-switch-when="choice">
   <md-input-container class="md-block">
      <label style="font-size: 130%; white-space: normal;" for="{{element.section_element_name}}">{{element.section_element_label}}</label>
      <md-select id={ {element.section_element_name}} type="selectbasic" value={{element.q_value}} ng-model="element.answer">
      <md-option ng-repeat="option in element.section_element_choices" value="{{option.element_choice_value}}">
         {{option.element_choice_label}}
      </md-option>
      </md-select>
   </md-input-container>
</div>
<div ng-switch-when="boolean">
   <md-checkbox id={ {element.section_element_name}} ng-model="element.answer">{{element.section_element_label}}</md-checkbox>
</div>
<div ng-switch-when="glide_date">
   <md-input-container>
      <label style="font-size: 130%; white-space: normal;" for="{{element.section_element_name}}">{{element.section_element_label}}</label>
      <md-datepicker id={ {element.section_element_name}} ng-model="element.answer" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
   </md-input-container>
</div>
```

When the form is submitted, we see an error: `The ng-model for md-datepicker must be a Date instance. Currently the model is a: string`

How can we modify the code so that the ng-model for just mddatepicker's get transformed into a date format?

Comment: I've found the best way to handle this is to transform all json date strings into date objects using momentjs in my centralized data service that is responsible for all http calls.  That way I'm always dealing with date objects throughout the rest of my code (controllers, services, etc.)

Comment: You can use momentjs or `new Date()`

Comment: thanks @Zooly and @jbrown!  I'd rather not use momentjs if possible.  How can I accomplish this with new Date()?

Comment: You have to parse your element.answer in a date format. It's currently a string var